# Angular2 : Login Page to restrict access to entire app

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem.
In my Angular2 app I would like to redirect all my "routes" to a login page when no user is authenticated. I'm aware about the routes, guards etc...

But in the [official "Routing & Navigation" documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard), the login form to access the "Admin" component is loaded in the router-outlet.

In my case, I would like that my App is not reachable when not logged in.

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: shouldn't you implement that in the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by myself reading the [official Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and using *Child Routes* & *CanActivate Guard*

I pushed on Sample on [my GitHub](https://github.com/An0d/angular-login-sample)